# pairplot columns from multiple dataframes labelled by classes from the category column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I am not sure how to do this but I believe is doable. I have three `dataframes` having the same column definition but dataset from different years. I then want to pairplot the numeric columns taking the columns one-by-one and plotting the data from these `df`s appropriately labeling the set for which data comes from. The objective is to understand the pattern in data for each column as compared by year.

I illustrate what I mean with these 2 `dataframes` where dataset in `df1` is from year `2018` and `df2` from year `2019` respectively:

```
df1
          id      speed    accelaration      jerk      mode
0          1      1.94     -1.01             1.05      foot
1          1      0.93      0.04            -0.17      foot
2          3      0.50     -0.16             0.05      bike
3          3      0.57      0.05             0.19      bike
4          5      3.25     -0.13            -0.09      bus
5          5      0.50     -0.25             0.25      bus
6          5      0.25      0.10             0.25      bus

df2
          id    speed   accelaration      jerk      mode
0         17      1.5      0.00           0.00      foot
1         17      1.5      0.00          -0.30      foot
2         17      1.5     -0.30           0.06      foot
3         15     4.55      0.01          -0.36      bike
4         15     4.57     -0.35           0.02      bike
5         87     9.82     -0.29          -0.12      bus
6         87     8.65     -0.78           0.07      bus
```

Ignoring the `id` column, I would like to get a result that looks like this figure (this is just an illustration of the intended result that I draw):

[image]

Simply calling `sns.pairplot()` twice for each `df` will not give the intended result, as I did that:

```
sns.pairplot(df1, vars=df1.columns[1:4], hue='mode')
sns.pairplot(df2, vars=df2.columns[1:4], hue='mode')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Can someone help describe how the intended answer could be obtained from this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Given the dataframe, add a `'year'` column to each one
- Use `pandas.concat` to combine the dataframes

  - Reset the index, but don't drop it. The index will be used as the x-axis, since one hasn't been provided. This will maintain the relative position of the data from each dataframe
- Stack `'speed'`, `'acceleration'`, and `'jerk'` into one column, `'event'`, to create a long, tidy format, dataframe.
- Plot the data with a [`seaborn.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) and mapped with a [`seaborn.scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html).

  - The `'index'` column, not the `dfl.index`, is used as the `x-axis`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# add year to the dataframes
df1['year'] = 2018
df2['year'] = 2019

# combine the dataframes
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index()

# stack the dataframe into a long (tidy) format
dfl = df.set_index(['index', 'id', 'mode', 'year']).stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_4': 'event', 0: 'value'})

# display(dfl)
   index  id  mode  year         event  value
0      0   1  foot  2018         speed   1.94
1      0   1  foot  2018  accelaration  -1.01
2      0   1  foot  2018          jerk   1.05
3      1   1  foot  2018         speed   0.93
4      1   1  foot  2018  accelaration   0.04
5      1   1  foot  2018          jerk  -0.17
6      2   3  bike  2018         speed   0.50
7      2   3  bike  2018  accelaration  -0.16
8      2   3  bike  2018          jerk   0.05
9      3   3  bike  2018         speed   0.57


# plot a FacetGrid mapped with a scatterplot
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=dfl, row='event', col='mode', hue='year')
g.map(sns.scatterplot, 'index', 'value').add_legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), loc='center left')
g.fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this wonderful answer. Now I can take a sip some coffee.

Comment: @arilwan glad this works for you. 2:36am here. off to bed. Enjoy your coffee :)